# Cell formatting doesn't apply to VB entered data

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'd like to know how to "apply" cell formatting to a cell when we don't write manually.

I have a vb.net application which enter the date and time to a cell in excel. The cells are formatted to display the date only as 16/04/2013.

When the application enter the date, excel displays it as a string so with the time. But if I double click to edit the cell then confirm without changing anything it formats the cell right.

Here are the screens

The last 5 are entered by the application.

I edited the n°66 then confirmed by enter and it is how I want it

[image]

Thank you

EDIT: Here is the code I use

```
Dim day As Date
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = False
oExcel.cells(6, 3).Select()
While oExcel.ActiveCell.Value <> Nothing
    oExcel.ActiveCell.OffSet(1, 0).Select()
End While
oExcel.ScreenUpdating = True

day = DateValue(Now)
oExcel.ActiveCell.Value = day & " " & TimeOfDay
oExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = timeOutput
```

EDIT2: Found a workaround

I found a way to convert the string to a number in excel here is the code:

```
Dim writeThis As String = day & " " & TimeOfDay
With oExcel.ActiveCell
  .OffSet(0, 10).Value = writeThis
  .Formula = "=" & oExcel.ActiveCell.OffSet(0, 10).Address & "+0"
  .Formula = oExcel.ActiveCell.Value
  .OffSet(0, 10).Value = Nothing
  .Offset(0, 1).Value = timeOutput
End With
```

I'm not sure it's the best way to do it but it works so i'm happy with it.
Thank you Siddharth for all your help :)

Comment: How are you writing to the excel cell from VB.Net? Can you share the code?

Comment: You have to format the column before writing to it if the date is a "string" and then write to the cell using `cell.Formula = strdate`

Comment: Could you show us your code? How do you enter the values?

Comment: Indeed I am here is the part that writes it
`selectDate()

day = DateValue(Now)

oExcel.ActiveCell.Value = day & " " & TimeOfDay

oExcel.ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = timeOutput`
But I'm not sure what you meant by formatting the column

Comment: You are doing this from VB.Net? Also please do not post the code in the comments. It is very difficult to read them. Edit your question and paste the code there :)

Comment: How have you declared `Day` ?

Answer (score 0):

See like you are writing to an existing file. If you would have been writing to a new file the above code would have worked as you wanted.

In the existing file, the column/cell is formatted as text and hence your date is stored as text.

If the entire Column is storing dates then see this example (Change as applicable)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    '~~> Open Existing Workbook
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")

    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Set the relebant sheet that we want to work with
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Day As Date = DateValue(Now)
    Dim TimeOfDay As Date = TimeOfDay

    With xlWorkSheet
        '~~> Directly type the values that we want
        .Columns(1).numberformat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        .Range("A1").Value = Day & " " & TimeOfDay
    End With

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

else if you want to format just the cell then see this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    '~~> Define your Excel Objects
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    '~~> Open Existing Workbook
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Sample.xlsx")

    '~~> Display Excel
    xlApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Set the relebant sheet that we want to work with
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim Day As Date = DateValue(Now)
    Dim TimeOfDay As Date = TimeOfDay

    With xlWorkSheet
        '~~> Directly type the values that we want
        With .Range("A1")
            .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            .Value = Day & " " & TimeOfDay
        End With
    End With

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '
End Sub
```

Comment: But my column is already formatted to dd/mm/yyyy. If I enter it manually it is correctly formatted. I tried adding `ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"` but it's just the same

Comment: May I see your excel file? Something is not right. I have tested the above code before posting :)

Comment: I just tested it with your file and wrote to cell C76 and it works just fine http://wikisend.com/download/964604/untitled.png

Comment: you wrote it via VB? I tried and it's not working :/ there is something weird going on here http://www.mediafire.com/view/?olwrldpw2dnhcqc

Comment: I just tried with this code and it doens't work.. really weird.
Maybe excel settings or something?

Comment: What if you change `.Value = Day & " " & TimeOfDay` to `.Formula = Day & " " & TimeOfDay`

Comment: no but I think the problem is not the code it must be something in Excel because when I press F2 then Enter it's right

Comment: Pressing F2 and pressing enter is the same as writing `.Formula`

Comment: Can you zip your vb.net project and upload it? Let me do some more testing with it?

Comment: I'm in class right now but as soon as I get home I'll do that

Comment: Your solution file is only 1KB?

Comment: I can't open it here. which VS version are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio Express 2012